# Should I say within 1-2 weeks or in 1-2 weeks?

Tags: word-usage

within 1-2 weeks or in 1-2 weeks.
Are they the same?
Which one is right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both *within X-time* and *in X-time* define a TIMESPAN which runs from the 'current' time you are talking about to a point X-after that.

- Bob will finish in/within two weeks ... *TIMESPAN runs from now until two weeks from now.*
- Bob will finish in/within two weeks after he gets an approval ... *TIMESPAN runs from the point when Bob gets approval until a date two weeks later.*
- Last Wednesday Bob said he would finish in/within two weeks ... *TIMESPAN runs from last Wednesday until a date two weeks after that—next Wednesday.*

But *within X-time* and *in X-time* mean two different things.

- *Within X-time* means that Bob will finish at some time **during** TIMESPAN. He will definitely finish before the end of TIMESPAN, but it may be at the very beginning of TIMESPAN or the very end of TIMESPAN or any point in between.
- *In X-time* means that Bob will finish at the **end** of TIMESPAN.

In your example, where you give a range for X-time, TIMESPAN is correspondingly vague, but the vagueness only affects the location of the end of TIMESPAN; it doesn't change the meaning.

- *Bob will finish within one or two weeks* means Bob will finish sometime between now and one or two weeks from now.
- *Bob will finish in one or two weeks* means Bob will finish sometime between one week from now and two weeks from now.

Answer (score 0):

They can both be correct. **within** implies a limit, saying that you're not sure how long something will take, but it won't be more than one or two weeks. **in** suggests that it probably won't be less than a week. With these lengths of time, the two expressions are almost identical, but if the time were longer, then the difference might be important.